# Android's certain button cannot pressed

Tags: custom-roms, 9.0-pie, oneplus-x

Im facing issue cant press certain button (i.e. **VPN ok button, chrome agree t&c**), as seen in the video

[Screen Record (GDrive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Azig30sNivf_3BLTq-miqWLJCQSb5DkZ)

Currently i am using 

`Ressurection Remix 7.0 (Android Pie/9)
OnePlus X E1003`

GApps is stock, **but** removed certain apps such as pixel/google rom as it may conflict with previous try of installation.

PS: **i wil post on rom's xda forum later**

Comment: Try to clear cache and data of chrome browser, I know that shown is chrome's first open page(without any data), force close chrome and have a try

Comment: I already try that, and somehow i could bypass first page. Now, its running normal

Thanks for the answer